# Set attributes based on active media query class in scss (or css)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, media-queries

If I have an element as such (using Bootstrap css):

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mydiv">
   some text here
</div>
```

I would like to be able to do something like this (example in SCSS):

```scss
.mydiv {
   &:not(.col-sm-6) {
       font-weight:bold;
   }
   &:not(.col-md-3) {
       text-transform:uppercase;
   }
}
```

So the `col-sm-*` and `col-lg-*` take care of resizing the container according to their respective `@media` queries, but I would also like to apply a certain style when one of them is active vs. the other.

The example code obviously doesn't work (since the div always has the .col-sm-6 and .col-md-3 classes).

I know i can create my own @media queries, or customize bootstrap.css media queries and add .mydiv to them, but i have several modules and would like to keep their respective CSS (SCSS) separate without having to also create multiple @media queries in each of them.

Comment: What does *"when one of them is active vs. the other"* mean?

Comment: when a browser window >480px wide col-sm-* applies, when the browser window >992px wide col-md-* applies. check the bootstrap homepage.